# Unable to make calls with asterisk and google voice

Tags: asterisk, google

I am unable to make or receive calls with asterisk and google voice.  I recall having used this setup years ago, so I expect it should work, but just need an ever so subtle tweak.

I can see that I am connected:

```
*CLI> xmpp show connections
Jabber Users and their status:
       [xx] xx@gmail.com     - Connected
----
   Number of clients: 1
```

With asterisk in verbose mode, this is the output I get:

```
*CLI>   == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
       > 0x7ff3b40073a0 -- Strict RTP learning after remote address set to: 192.168.1.15:4010
    -- Executing [18008008000@xx-google-out:1] Dial("SIP/xx-00000000", "Motif/xx/+18008008000@voice.google.com,,r") in new stack
    -- Called Motif/xx/+18008008000@voice.google.com
    -- Motif/+18008008000@voice.google.com-d60e is proceeding passing it to SIP/xx-00000000
  == Everyone is busy/congested at this time (1:0/0/1)
    -- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/xx-00000000' status is 'CHANUNAVAIL'
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
       > 0x7ff3b4000910 -- Strict RTP learning after remote address set to: 192.168.1.15:4012
    -- Executing [18008008000@xx-google-out:1] Dial("SIP/xx-00000001", "Motif/xx/+18008008000@voice.google.com,,r") in new stack
    -- Called Motif/xx/+18008008000@voice.google.com
    -- Motif/+18008008000@voice.google.com-dce1 is proceeding passing it to SIP/xx-00000001
  == Everyone is busy/congested at this time (1:0/0/1)
    -- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/xx-00000001' status is 'CHANUNAVAIL'
       > Saved useragent "CSipSimple_achill-22/r2457" for peer xx
```

extensions.conf:

```
[general]
static=yes
;writeprotect=no

; added from forum ...
writeprotect=yes

priorityjumping=no
autofallthrough=yes

[global]
;DIALOUT=9
;RINGTIME=30

[default]
include => xx-google-out
include => xx-google-in

;https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Calling+using+Google

[xx-google-out]
;exten => _1XXXXXXXXXX,1,Dial(Motif/xx/${EXTEN}@voice.google.com,,r)
;exten => _XXXXXXXXXX,1,Dial(Motif/xx/${EXTEN}@voice.google.com,,r)
;exten => _+1XXXXXXXXXX,1,Dial(Motif/xx/${EXTEN}@voice.google.com,,r)
exten => _1XXXXXXXXXX,1,Dial(Motif/xx/+${EXTEN}@voice.google.com,,r)


[xx-google-in]
exten => s,1,NoOp()
 same => n,Set(crazygooglecid=${CALLERID(name)})
 same => n,Set(stripcrazysuffix=${CUT(crazygooglecid,@,1)})
 same => n,Set(CALLERID(all)=${stripcrazysuffix})
 same => n,Dial(SIP/xx,20,D(:1))
```

modules.conf

```
[modules]
autoload=yes

;#load => chan_motif.so
;#load => res_xmpp.so
```

motif.conf:

```
[xx]
context=xx-google-in
disallow=all
allow=ulaw,g722
connection=xx
```

rtp.conf:

```
[general]
; specify start and end port range so firewall rules are easier to write
rtpstart=10000
rtpend=20000
icesupport=yes
```

sip.conf:

```
[xx]
allow=all
allowguest=no
type=peer
secret=SECRETGOESHERE
host=dynamic
context=xx-google-out
```

xmpp.conf:

```
[general]
[xx]
type=client
serverhost=talk.google.com
username=xx@gmail.com
secret=SECRETGOESHERE
priority=25
port=5222
usetls=yes
usesasl=yes
status=available
statusmessage=Asterisk Instance - Google Talk - VoIP
timeout=5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asterik to Google Voice integration has been falling out of favor at Google gradually for a while. Third-party XMPP has not been officially supported since 2014-2015, and the remaining old implementations have been dis-commissioned now.

From [Google Voice Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/voice/NYRy5U31o98)

> Update regarding XMPP Interop Capabilities
>
> de Aaron G. - Product Support Manager  28/04
>
> Starting on June 18, 2018, we will finish
>   migrating the last of our XMPP interop capabilities for Google Voice
>   to the new Voice platform. This migration will enable us to create
>   powerful new VoIP features that will both benefit and delight Voice
>   users.
>
> If you use Google Voice with a supported device using the XMPP interop
>   capability, please contact your vendor to determine the best migration
>   path to avoid a service disruption.